# Problema para hacer scroll horizontal sobre lista de elementos deslizable

Tags: reactjs, css3

Estoy haciendo una lista de imágenes que se deslizan horizontalmente al hacer scroll, y cuando se posicione el puntero del mouse sobre una imagen (hover), esta se oculte y se muestre en su lugar una tarjeta con más información. Algo similar a lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para implementar el efecto hice uso de la propiedad CSS `position` con sus valores `absolute` y `relative`, pero el inconveniente que no puedo solventar es que se pierde la posibilidad de realizar el scroll horizontal.
Estoy trabajando con `React` y `CSS` puro sin ninguna otra librería de terceros y (por el momento) con el Navegador Chrome.

El código es el siguiente:

Fichero `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Card from './Card'
import { actors, actresses } from '../stars'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hollywood</h1>
      <div className="row">
        <h2>Actors</h2>
        <div className="row__stars">
          {actors.map(actor => (
            <Card star={actor} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <h2>Actresses</h2>
        <div className="row__stars">
          {actresses.map(actress => (
            <Card star={actress} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Fichero `Card.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

const Card = ({ star }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card1">
        <img src={star.url} alt={star.name} />
      </div>
      <div className="card2">
        <img src={star.url} alt={star.name} />
        <div className="card2__description">
          <p>{star.name}</p>
          <p>{`Age: ${star.age}`}</p>
          <p>{`Gender: ${star.gender}`}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Fichero `style.css`:

```
body {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 20px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.row__stars {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.row__stars::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card2 {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 325px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card1 > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card2 > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.card2__description {
  background-color: #222;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card2__description > p:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card:hover .card1 {
  display: none;
}

.card:hover .card2 {
  display: block;
}
```

De todos modos dejo el enlace del código en Stackblitz: https://react-kuzg6p.stackblitz.io

Muchas gracias de antemano por su tiempo.

Aclaración: Si abren con toda la pantalla del navegador no se puede ver el problema puesto que se visualizan todas las imágenes. Coloqué 5 por una cuestión de simplicidad. Si achican la pantalla lateralmente podrán visualizar con claridad el desperfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede lograr el scroll horizontal con los arrow keys si agregas la propiedad *overflow: scroll* al body  y *display: none* al webkit  en el css:

```
body {
    ...
    overflow: scroll ;  

}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

el inconveniente es que el scroll afecta a ambos rows ya que el body esta siendo afectado.

Si deseas que solamente se muevan los rows de tarjetas de manera independiente, una manera de hacerlo seria usando useState y useRef

en App.js

```
const  App = ()  => {
    // crea un ref para cada fila de tarjetas
    const actorsRef = useRef(null)  
    const actressesRef = useRef(null)  


return (
<div>
  <h1>Hollywood</h1>     
  <div  className="row">           
    <div className="row__stars">
      <h2>Actors</h2> 
      
      <div  //Aqui agregue un wrapper adicional a la fila para las propiedades 
        className ="row_stars_wrap" 
        ref = {actorsRef} // actualiza el ref                
        tabIndex = {-1} // asigna un tabindex para poder aplicar el focus()
      >             
        {actors.map(actor => (
          <Card 
            actorsRef = {actorsRef}             
            key = {new Date().getTime().toString()+ Math.random()}
            star={actor}  
            actors={actors}        
            />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  ...
 // para el segundo row los cambios son similares
</div>
```

);
}

en Card.js

```
const Card = ({ 
    star, 
    actorsRef, 
    actressesRef,
    actors
}) => {

  const [showbigCard, setShowBigCard] = useState(false); // esta variable permite 
        //mostrar la tarjeta grande al estar el puntero del mouse encima de ella

 //esta funcion cambia el focus() a la fila para que funcione el scroll 
  const handleMouseEnter = (e) => {        
    actors.some(a => a.name === e.target.alt)
      ? actorsRef.current.focus()  
      : actressesRef.current.focus()  

    setShowBigCard(true)
    
  }

   // esta variable solo actualiza la propiedad height de la tarjeta debajo del puntero del mouse
  const style = {   
    height: 250,
  }

  return (
    <div 
      className="card" 
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={() => setShowBigCard(false)}
      style ={showbigCard ? style : null }
    >
      {showbigCard ? (
        <div className = "card2-cont">
          <div className="card2">
            <img src={star.url} alt={star.name}  />
            <div className="card2__description">
              <p>{star.name}</p>
              <p>{`Age: ${star.age}`}</p>
              <p>{`Gender: ${star.gender}`}</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
       
      ) : (
        <div className="card1">
          <img src={star.url} alt={star.name} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

y en styles.css:

```
body {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto"; 
  /* overflow: scroll; */
}


/* 
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
} */


* {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 20px;
}

.row {  
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
}

.row_stars_wrap {  
  display: flex;  
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.row_stars_wrap:focus {
  outline: none; 
}

.row__stars {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y :visible;
}

.row::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.row__stars::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}



.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card2-cont {
  position: relative;
}

.card2 {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 325px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-100px)  translateX(-40px);
}

.card1 > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card2 > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.card2__description {
  background-color: #222;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card2__description > p:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Aqui puedes ver el codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-kilby-z1gpg?file=/src/Card.js:64-1145